# How to populate partially a formset in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I’m having difficulty pre-populating only some fields in a model formset.

For context, the project is an attendance app where there will be a grid with  columns:the students name,the date,and if the student is present or not.

The goal is that the column with the students name is filled with all the students names(already saved in Database from the student model),and that the date is the same for all the rows.So that when the user is going to take attendance,he only has to click in the checkbox of the attendance.
I've found a question similar to mine,but it was not answered([pre-populating partial Initial data in a Django formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417005/pre-populating-partial-initial-data-in-a-django-formset)).
If needed,I can post my codes for help.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: yes please post your code to better understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

I accidently stumbled upon the solution when I was tinkering with the code.
Here is how I did it.

```
Views.py
def cadastrar_presenca(request, pk):
all_presencas = Presenca.objects.all()
all_alunos = Aluno.objects.filter(turma_id=pk)
all_turmas = Turma.objects.all()
turma = Turma.objects.get(pk=pk)
i = 0
PresencaFormSet = modelformset_factory(Presenca, form=PresencaForm, extra=all_alunos.count())
id_turma = get_object_or_404(Turma, pk=pk)
if request.method == 'GET':
    formset = PresencaFormSet(queryset=Presenca.objects.none())
elif request.method == "POST":
    formset = PresencaFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for form in formset:
            presenca = form.save(commit=False)
            presenca.RA = all_alunos[i]
            presenca.save()
            i = i + 1
        return redirect('/alunos_cursinho') #voltar para a url alunos-cursinho(urls.py)
return render(request, 'cadastrar_presenca.html', {'turma': turma, 'id_turma': id_turma,
                                                   'all_turmas': all_turmas, 'all_alunos': all_alunos,
                                                   'formset':formset, 'all_presencas' : all_presencas})
```

And the form:

```
class PresencaForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Presenca
    fields = ('data', 'Periodo1', 'Periodo2',)
    widgets = {'data': DateInput()}
```